# How do you add emoji reactions in embed? Discord.JS V14

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, bots

I used to use discord js V12 and was able to **add two emojis** (like, dislike). When executing the command, an **embed was sent to the chat and automatically, after the embed was sent**, the emojis I mentioned were added as reactions. I currently use **the discord.js V14** version and I can't understand how I can do this. If possible, could you explain my doubt about how to add this to the embed?

Below I leave a part of the code of my command that is the part responsible for sending the embed "embed_sugestao" and the embed embed_logs_sugestao". **I would like to know how I can do it so that after the embed "embed_sugestao" is sent, the reactions are automatically added** with the emojis I mentioned above (dislike and dislike)! Thank you!!

```
interaction.reply({ embeds: [embed_sugestao] , content: `**${interaction.user}, sugestão enviada com sucesso!**` }).then( () => {
  canal_logs_sugestoes.send({ embeds: [embed_logs_sugestao] })
  embed_sugestao.react('')
}).catch( () => {
  console.log(`Ocorreu um Erro no Comando /sugerir`)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

`embed_suggestao` is **just the embed**, but you need to react to the message sent when replying to the interaction.

[Here](https://old.discordjs.dev/#/docs/discord.js/main/class/CommandInteraction?scrollTo=reply) you can see that `CommandInteraction.reply(...)` returns a promise to either a message or an "InteractionResponse," which can be fetched into a message. [Here](https://old.discordjs.dev/#/docs/discord.js/main/class/Message?scrollTo=react) you can see that `react` is called on a Message object, not an embed object.

Here's how it should be done:

```js
interaction.reply({ embeds: [embed_sugestao] , content: `**${interaction.user}, sugestão enviada com sucesso!**` }).then(message => {
  canal_logs_sugestoes.send({ embeds: [embed_logs_sugestao] })
  message.react('')
}).catch( () => {
  console.log(`Ocorreu um Erro no Comando /sugerir`)
})
```

I don't believe this is a difference between V12 and V14; I'm fairly certain this is just a common slip-up that's bound to happen to everyone at one point or another.